# Using Generate Near Table and keep the ID attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, proximity

I try to use near table between two datasets to calculate the nearest distance. The original data is as the right one, and the near table generated is as the left one. The problem is the attribute of "IN_FID" and "NEAR_FID", none of them keep the correct values from the data. The ID number is important to me, how can I keep it? I have tried to join the attribute, but it turns out "Null" values.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"NEAR_FID" and "IN_FID" fields always refer to OBJECTID field of the feature class (in case of shapefile it is usually OID field). Every feature class has this field. This field is bounded to feature class and has not relation to your data.

So if you wish to join your near table to your data by custom id field, you must firstly join near table to your layer with OBJECTID field and then layer to your data by your custom ID field.